# Center text and image in navbar and put the navbar on the top of the page

Tags: html, css

I'm new to HTML and CSS and I'm making my first website. I came across this issue in my project and I can't find the way to solve it. For some reason, my navbar isn't sitting on the top of my page. I also want to know how I can centre my image and also text so it's inline with the box.

**CSS/HTML**

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: 'Arial', serif;
 background-color: #232323
}

.nav {
 background-color: #b73844;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 list-style: none;
 text-align: left
}

.nav > li {
 display: inline-block;
 padding-right: 25px;
}

.nav > li > a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #ffffff;
}

.nav > li > a:hover {
 color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>AccountPanda - Home</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css">
</head>

<body>
 <ul class="nav">
  <a href="index.html">
     <img src="images/logo.png" title="AccountPanda" style="width:225px;height:75px;">
  </a> 
  <li><a href="#">Accounts</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li> 
 </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can add <ul class="nav" style="margin-top:0px"> to stick it to top.

Comment: Have you tried `display: inline;`?  And also if you want something to be centered just use `margin: 0 auto;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using flex you can align it center. Also your class `nav` is on a `ul` element which has its default properties like margin, padding etc. You can either override them or use them. See below.

```css
/* CSS Document */
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Arial', serif;
    background-color: #232323
}

.nav {
    background-color: #b73844;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 10px;
}

.nav > li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 25px;
}

.nav > li > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.nav > li > a:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <ul class="nav">
        <a href="index.html">
            <img src="images/logo.png" title="AccountPanda" style="width:225px;height:75px;">
        </a>    
        <li><a href="#">Accounts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>    
    </ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

`vertical-align: middle` and `line-height: 0` is what you're looking for.

```css
.nav > li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 25px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 0;
}
```

I also wrapped the `<a>` that holds the image with a `li`, so all items in the `ul` are `li`:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li>
      <a href="index.html">
        <img src="//placehold.it/225x75" title="AccountPanda" style="width:225px;height:75px;">
       </a> 
    </li>   
    <li><a href="#">Accounts</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>    
</ul>
```

[image]

Plunker Demo here: http://plnkr.co/edit/PUpoQcGn6qexWD1hkDKF?p=preview

Comment: How do i do this also for the logo as thats not doing the same, also have the header touch the top of the page, sorry for any inconvenience

Comment: Updated answer and plunker. The fix was to add `line-height: 0;` to the `.nav > li` selector.